# Level of reading consistency in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

If I have 4 CPDS with 3 machines in each and a replication factor 3 in which a mapreduce is implemented. What level of consistency do you think is most appropriate, considering that it is fast at the same time?

Comment: What is CPDS? Datacenters?

Comment: Yes. I have 4 Datacenters.

Comment: so network topology with RF=3 for each DC, across 4 DCs, totaling 12 replicas? or just RF=3? Can you include your actual replication factor declaration? Also which DC does your app live in, is it ok to use local consistencies?

Comment: The application is distributed among the 4 data centers.
Each Datacenter has 3 nodes with FR = 3.
It would be advisable to use local consistency, although speed and high availability are more important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MapReduce jobs I would recommend to use `LOCAL_ONE` as the fastest.  This of course depends on your application, but usually for Spark jobs this consistency level is used most often.

But I really wondering about this setup - in your case, you have a copy of your data on every machine. In typical setups, analytical workload (MapReduce or Spark) is usually put into separate data center, where the RF is different from transactional - this gives you better utilization.  For example, you can combine 2 DCs into one with 6 machines, and use RF=2, so you can put more data into that DC.  But of course, this depends on availability requirements for your MapReduce jobs - are you ok with some downtime if DC isn't available, or not.

Comment: The system is used for data volumetry and analysis in real time through a web platform, so speed and availability are important. The data is also updated very frequently.In each data center there is a copy of the data.

Comment: Anyway, I wouldn't have so many DCs, with replication to every machine...

Comment: Another question, if one of the task, will get "slightly stale" data - how heavily it will affect results? I believe that for batch-style jobs it's usually not an issue.

Comment: Indeed, it would not be a problem